# Getting an array from Firebase Database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've a [String] Array under the "urls" key. How can i get it out? Here is my structure:

[image: Here is my structure:]

Answer (score 0):

You can read it by using an observer to the urls reference and initializing an array with its value.

```
ref = Database.database().reference()

ref.child("sectionList").child("name of").child("urls")observe(.value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

  var urls : [String] = snapshot.children

}
```

"This function takes two parameters: an instance of FIRDataEventType and a closure.
The event type specifies what event you want to listen for. The code listens for a .value event type, which in turn listens for all types of changes to the data in your Firebase database—add, removed, and changed.
When the change occurs, the database updates the app with the most recent data.
The app is notified of the change via the closure, which is passed an instance of FIRDataSnapshot. The snapshot, as its name suggests, represents the data at that specific moment in time. To access the data in the snapshot, you use the value property."
 Source:(https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2)

Comment: i couldn't cast snapshot.children to [String]

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. snapshot.children is a JSON, not an array. It could be casted to a dictionary of type [String : AnyObject]()

Answer (score 0):

I got it like this

```
    let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "sectionList")
    ref.child("name of").child("urls").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (dataSnapshot:DataSnapshot) in
        for object in dataSnapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            for obj in object.value as! NSArray {
                print("value = \(obj)")
            }
        }

    })
```